# context:property-placeholder not working for multiple files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have got 2 properties file with me. I have mentioned both the files in the `context:property-placeholder` like this...

```
<context:property-placeholder location="conf/ConfServer.conf,conf/LicenseSettings.properties" />
```

Also I have tried this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="conf/ConfServer.conf,conf/LicenseSettings.properties" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>conf/LicenseSettings.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
   <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Both the above mentioned methods I have tried are not working.
Can anyone spot out the mistake and help me out of this?
I already referred to [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?48848-context-property-placeholder-question), but it didn't work good for me.

Comment: Can you load them individually?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can specify multiple `context:property-placeholder` tags within your configuration file.  You can also specify which will be loaded first using the `order` attribute.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="conf/ConfServer.conf" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
<context:property-placeholder location="conf/LicenseSettings.properties" order="2" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. On trying this, the result is same. The `conf/ConfServer.conf` is working good but not the 2nd file.
Do you want me to post the code, I am using to initialize the variables read from the file?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, your method worked good. Thank you very much. It took me around 2 hours to solve this. Thank you once again.

Comment: Using Spring 4.1.5, I only managed to use a single context:property-placeholder tag successfully, however the "location" attribute accepts multiple comma-separated locations. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3407752/218139

Comment: I had the same issue and ignore-unresolvable="true" fixed my problem.

Comment: Can I have two property file , one is for prod , one for dev?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try referring these properties from project root directory

`conf/ConfServer.conf`

`conf/LicenseSettings.properties`

These may not be referred correctly.