# Spring - Set properties before load resources in applicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

in my applicationContext.xml I have a list of spring cfg files.

```
<import resource="classpath:resource1.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/resource1.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/resource1.xml"/>    
<import resource="classpath:resource1.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:resource1.xml"/>
```

And these files need some properties that are setted.
When I'm set these properties in JVM every runs OK.
But when load by properties file in my applicationContext, I receive an exception because the app couldn't "translate" the property key(${key}) in value.

```
<bean id="propSource" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="order" value="-999"/>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:/application.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I think that spring load import xml files before to load properties file.
How I can solve this?

Thnks

Comment: Note that `META-INF` is not on the classpath.

Comment: In this case that META-INF is in the classpath because these xml files are inside a jar that I'm using in my project. Tnks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403773/using-multiple-property-files-via-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-in-multiple-pr

Comment: Hi Shailendra thanks for response. I'm just trying this method but not got success.

Comment: Where is the `propSource` bean defined? Where is the bean that causes the exception defined?

Comment: The propSource and imports are defined in applicationContext.xml