# Spring MVC: Access values from properties file (the Jar containing the properties file) using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, properties-file

I am using maven multi-module project. In one module i define all configuration for project, in which my properties files and spring xml configurations files are exist. I this module i define `<util:properties id="urls" location="classpath*:urls.properties"/>` tag in my `application-context` file. I also have `db-configuration` file, and my db-credentials are also fetch from properties file, at that time there is no problem. My this configuration maven module is inject to another module which is basically a web module. where we create Spring MVC controller. When i tying to access values from properties file (the file come from config module) using spring `@Value` annotation, it generates an exception. Because `@Value` annotation unable to find the value of my properties key. following is my code:

```
@Value("${base.url}")
private String baseURL;
```

properties file: urls.properties

```
base.url = http://localhost:8080/demo/
```

Following is Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'base.url' in string value "${base.url}"
```

Comment: You need `<context:property-placeholder />` to be able to replace the properties. `<util:properties />` is only for loading a properties file and make it available as a `java.util.Properties` object in the context it will not be used for replacement.

Comment: @M.Deinum i also have a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for my `db-cridentials`. I think if i declare `<context:property-placeholder />`, it creates a conflict.

Comment: If you already have it you have to make it aware of your other properties. It doesn't just look at all the properties in your context you have to tell it which files and/or properties to take into account.

Comment: @M.Deinum if i want to use multiple properties file, then what ?

Comment: You are using `@Value` is it possible to switch to Java Config? That way you can have multiple `@Configuration` classes which also have a `@PropertySource` annotation, that way you just need a single `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instance and each module/jar contributes its own configuration.

Comment: You can add multiple properties file to a `<context:property-placeholder />` to location attribute takes a comma separated list.

Comment: This post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403773/using-multiple-property-files-via-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-in-multiple-pr

Comment: @M.Deinum no it is not possible to switch to java configuration. If this is possible in java configuration, it is also some other way with xml configuration. According to this error, i think my application context unable to find the property place holder. because the properties file in jar.

Comment: The problem isn't in the fact that your properties file is or isn't there... The problem is that your property placeholder doesn't know anything about it. You are just loading it and that is all you do. Your properties basically only take up memory they aren't used.

Comment: Hey @M.Deinum when i use `<context:property-placeholder />` with comma separated properties file, it will work. Now i get value from properties file. Thanks for your help buddy.