# Find message in multiple properties files

Tags: java, spring, resourcebundle

In an application there are multiple properties file for managing exception messages, alerts, and some others text these file like this:

- core-message.properties
- databaseException.properties
  ...

in Service layer maybe a database call occurs and the database returns a key that exists in one the properties files, and I want get the value and raise the exception message to user interface layer.

if I know that the key in which properties file the code will be like this:

```
@Value("#{core['theExceptionKey']}") 
public String excpetionMessage; 

private void myMethod() {
throw new ExceptionClass(exceptionMessage);
}
```

I think spring can do that because when I use spring:message tag in jsp files spring does not know the key in which file but it loads the message correctly.

Comment: Can you load all properties to 1 property object? see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403773/using-multiple-property-files-via-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-in-multiple-pr

Comment: i load it but in the service side i cant define @value

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring `Environment` abstraction for that.

First you need to add Property Source to your Java Configuration file

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/mypacakge/core-message.properties")
public class AppConfig {
```

Or if you have multiple properties files

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:core-message.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
}) 
    public class AppConfig {
```

Add `PropertySourceConfigurer` to to your Java Configuration file

```
 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }
```

Now let's say that in your `core-message.properties` you have the following data

```
message.name=Hello
```

You can retrieve this data in any bean by autowiring `Environment` abstraction and then calling `env.getProperty()`

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

public void m1(){
String message = env.getProperty("message.name")` // will return Hello
```

---

`Environment` object provides interface to configure property sources and resolve properties. It provides convenience to read from a variety of sources: properties files, system environment variable, JVM system properties, servlet context parameters, and so on, which is very useful. For example :

```
    environment.getSystemProperties().put("message", "Hello");
    System.getProperties().put("message", "Hello");

    environment.getSystemProperties().get("message"); // retrieve property
    environment.getPropertySources() // allows manipulation of Properties objects
```

[Spring Reference Documentation - Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-environment)

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the key programmatically you can use the following:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
...
String something = env.getProperty("property.key.something");
```

Comment: it give me null for the key that exists in my properties file